# Python pyaudio error while recording from microphone

Tags: python, speech

I was trying to convert speech to text via pyaduio.The program was working fine for a few hours but suddenly my visual studio 2019 keeps on marking an error in the **6th line** for no reason.
Does anyone know how to fix it? tnx :)

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio

 r = sr.Recognizer()
 mic = sr.Microphone(device_index=1)
 with mic as source:
         audio_data = r.record(source, duration= 3)
         print("I recognize speaking")
         text = r.recognize_google(audio_data)       
         print("I heard: ",text)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal code example that reproduces your problem. Your provided code cannot run on its own.

Comment: now you  can run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that google api is restricted to certain amount of uses without paying, and I ran out of free uses.

Comment: You can also select your answer as the solution